# Lottie shifts position on iOS. Works fine on Windows & Android

Tags: javascript, html, ios, youtube-iframe-api, lottie

So i have this Lottie/iframe combination which im working on.
Since im just learning javascript, forgive me the messed up code.

To start the lottie animation and launch a youtube iframe (autoplay & unmuted), I used a button which is stacked ontop the Lottie to fit in a blank area of the animation.

This works fine on Windows & Android Browsers.
If loaded in Safari (MacOS and iOS) the lottie animation changes position and isn't aligned with the button anymore. When the animation is started, the lottie suddenly shifts position and is aligned again. If i lock the device (iPhone X) and unlock it again, the lottie returns to the wrong position.

This bug is only present on iOS Safari/Chrome. Sadly, I dont have a Mac to debug inside Safari directly. Maybe someone has an idea?

There are propably many more issues with the code, but it seems to work fine except of the described issue.
The youtube iframe isn't visible on codepen, because they block some of the necessary content. the display of the iframe works as intended on my website tho.

https://codepen.io/peplebe/pen/dyvJQMo

```
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>  
  
<script>
  window.onload = function(){ 
    var player = document.querySelector("lottie-player");
var play = document.querySelector(".start");
var stop = document.querySelector("#stop");
let ytiframe = document.getElementById('ytiframe');
play.onclick = function () {
    player.play(); 
  ytiframe.classList.toggle('fade');
};

    
};

   


</script>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
</head>
<style>

  
@-webkit-keyframes glowings {
  0% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000; }
  50% { background-color: #FF0000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000; }
  100% { background-color: #B20000; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000; }
}

@-moz-keyframes glowings {
  0% { background-color: #B20000; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000; }
  50% { background-color: #FF0000; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000; }
  100% { background-color: #B20000; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000; }
}

@-o-keyframes glowings {
  0% { background-color: #B20000; box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000; }
  50% { background-color: #FF0000; box-shadow: 0 0 40px #FF0000; }
  100% { background-color: #B20000; box-shadow: 0 0 3px #B20000; }
}

@keyframes glowings {
  0% { background-color: #ffd300; box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ffde00; }
  50% { background-color: #ffd300; box-shadow: 0 0 40px #ffde00; }
  100% { background-color: #ffd300; box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ffde00; }
}

.btn-glow {
  -webkit-animation: glowings 1500ms infinite;
  -moz-animation: glowings 1500ms infinite;
  -o-animation: glowings 1500ms infinite;
  animation: glowings 1500ms infinite;
  color: rgb(163,5,0);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 233px;
  left: 157px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 60px;
  transform: rotate(-0.5deg);
  background-color: rgba(208,207,207,0.72);
  border: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 199!important;
}
.btn-glow:hover {
  -webkit-animation: glowings 0ms infinite;
  -moz-animation: glowings 0ms infinite;
  -o-animation: glowings 0ms infinite;
  animation: glowings 0ms infinite;
  }
#ytiframe {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;  
  width: 250px;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;}
#ytiframe.fade {
  opacity:.5;
}
  .jukeboxcode{
    position: relative;
    bottom: -10px;
  }
</style>



<body data-rsssl=1>

<div class="jukeboxcode" style="height: 800px; width: 400px; background-color: rgba(25,254,1,0.14); ">

  <button id="fadebutton" class="start play btn-glow">INSERT COIN</button>



<div id="ytiframe" class="video" >
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MV_3Dpw-BRY?enablejsapi=1&playsinline=1"  frameborder="0" playsinline="1" allow="autoplay" ></iframe>
</div>
  

<script>
(function() {
    var player;
    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
        new YT.Player(document.querySelector('.video iframe'), {
            events: {
                onReady: function(e) {
                    player = e.target
                }
            }
        })
    }

    document.querySelector('.jukeboxcode .play').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        player.playVideo()
    })
})()
</script>


<lottie-player src="https://assets7.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_yc3xb5l6.json"  background="transparent"  speed="1"  style="z-index: 188; width: 400px; height: 550px;" ></lottie-player>



</div>
</body>
```

Best regards.

PS: I'm also looking to make the youtube player stop playing, as well as resetting the lottie animation on button click. If anyone has an idea on how to do so, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Final solution was to render the lottie as canvas not as svg. This fixed the bug.
Still not sure what caused it tho.

```
<lottie-player src="..."  background="transparent"  speed="1" renderer: 'canvas', style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"  loop controls autoplay></lottie-player>
```